# Datetime in 24 hours Clock format in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written this code for time calculation but my code is not accepting 24 hour time format. It is accepting only up to 12:59.

This is my code:

```
protected void TxtId_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)((TextBox)sender).Parent.Parent;

    TextBox txtTakenDate = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtTakenDate");
    TextBox txtTakenTime = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtTakenTime");
    TextBox txtReturnedDate = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtReturndDate");
    TextBox txtReturnedTime = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtReturndTime");

    TextBox txtmttr = (TextBox)currentRow.FindControl("txtmttr");
    string StartDate = txtTakenDate.Text;
    string StartTime = txtTakenTime.Text;
    DateTime StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact((StartDate + " " + StartTime), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    string EndDate = Convert.ToString(txtReturnedDate.Text);
    string EndTime = Convert.ToString(txtReturnedTime.Text);
    DateTime EndDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact((EndDate + " " + EndTime), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    TimeSpan TotalTime = EndDateTime.Subtract(StartDateTime);
    txtmttr.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int)TotalTime.TotalHours, TotalTime.Minutes);
}
```

Comment: I think there should be a rule of not helping people who push for urgency ... does anybody have a "non urgent" problem?

Comment: @Noctis dont take it otherwise. no need to be rude. sorry btw.

Comment: @SantanuMaulik Wasn't trying to be rude, but lately I see many people who are URGING others to HELP them ... This is not the spirit I would like to see in the community ... In any case, no offense meant, be more considerate in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `HH` instead of `hh` for 24 hour format date, i.e `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

> **HH** - The hour using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
>
> **hh** - The hour using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using the format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" instead of "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" for hours.